# Doing math with axios response results in NaN every time

Tags: javascript, axios, nan

I have the following `axios` call in my code. It should return a number from my `database` in the column `slots`. In the code below, the console log for the response shows the correct number, then I return it to process in another function, however when I try to do math with it, I get an `NaN` result!

I've even tried using `parseInt` and no luck there as well. Any advice?

```
function getCurrentSlotsAxios(group_id) {
   axios.get('group/' + group_id)
       .then( (response) => {
           console.log('getCurrentSlotsAxios ' + group_id +': ' + parseInt(response.data.slots)) //shows the correct # in console
           return parseInt(response.data.slots) //attempted parseInt in case it was returned as a string for some reason
       })
       .catch( function(error) {
           console.log(error)
           }
       )
  }
```

Then in another **function**:

```
let current_slots = getCurrentSlotsAxios(group_id)
console.log(current_slots + 1) // results in NaN whether I use parseInt or not :(
```

Comment: `getCurrentSlotsAxios` returns a Promise

Comment: If you log current_slots after running the function, what do you see?

Comment: `getCurrentSlotsAxios ` returns `undefined` i.e. nothing

Comment: ahh you guys are right, logging current_slots returns undefined...how do I have it return the actual number? Why does it show the correct number when console logged within the axios call?

Comment: @JaromandaX No. There is no return statement, so it does not return a promise. It returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Maribov See the link in the yellow box above your question.

Comment: @Maribov When you call the function, it immediately returns `undefined` and you try to add 1 to that, and that will give you `NaN`. The axios call happen sometime in the future, and when that happens, it have the correct value.

Comment: @Maribov You could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, I meant `axios.get` returns a Promise ... your function returns nothing